Been struggling with Cron job to execute python script in conda environment
I've been trying to make a cron job that should excute a python script in a conda environment. At first i had an issue with "import module error" due to executing the cript in base env.
So i added explicitly the path in crontab , PATH=/path/to/miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin
then set up a bash script "cron.sh" to recall the command that i would normally give in the terminal;
#!/bin/sh
python3 /absolute/path/to/my_script.py

and added log to crontab.
so my crontab looks like:
PATH=/path/to/miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin

* * * * * /absolute/path/to/cron.sh >> /absolute/path/to_log_file/clogs.log 2>&1

problem is i have nothing in log file and i don't understand where things  are messing up.
Any helps on this ?
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4
Conda info
conda info 

     active environment : base
    active env location : /config/miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /config/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 24.5.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.12.2.final.0
                 solver : libmamba (default)
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=haswell
                          __conda=24.5.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __linux=4.18.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /config/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /config/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /config/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /config/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /config/miniconda3/envs
                          /config/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/24.5.0 requests/2.32.2 CPython/3.12.2 Linux/4.18.0-477.27.1.el8_8.x86_64 ubuntu/20.04.4 glibc/2.31 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/24.1.0 libmambapy/1.5.8 aau/0.4.4 c/. s/. e/.
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


The duplicate shows you how to troubleshoot this type of problem. If the solutions there don't help, please [edit] to indicate what you have already done to troubleshoot this problem yourself (verify that you have write access to the output file, verify that the cron daemon is running, etc etc)

#!/bin/sh
python3 /absolute/path/to/my_script.py

This uses base python3, you should activate venv before calling python3, which can de done following way
#!/bin/sh
source /absolute/path/to/venv/bin/activate && python3 /absolute/path/to/my_script.py


tried it but did'nt work :  #!/bin/bash
source /config/miniconda3/envs/api_env/bin/activate
conda activate api_env
python3 /config/workspace/test/api.py

You don't need to put the call in a separate script file, just run it from cron directly anyway.

I figured it out. I'm sharing what i did in case anyone faces same issue.
So i removed the shell script as basically it complicates debugging and used directly cron as follows:









(date && /config/miniconda3/envs/api_env/bin/python3 /config/workspace/test/twg_api.py) >> /config/workspace/logapi.txt 2>&1
this solved my problem and does what i expect.









